# Is there a way to get the number of specials unlocked from Foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

I am trying to extract the number of specials unlocked at a venue from the Foursquare API, however I can only find a list of current specials. Is this possible? What is the end point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/campaigns/timeseries, but you must be a manager of the specials campaign to access these details.